# While reviewing First Posts, should links for question or answers still be clickable?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I'm not sure if this is a feature or a bug. When you are reviewing questions for first timers, in there are ***test questions***. You are still able to click the links for the original questions, if that was really a test if the reviewer is looking on what is looking on, should this link be a dead link?

[image]

Comment: Whenever I felt the need, I've always found a quick way to get to the original question and add whatever contributions I felt were needed outside of the review system. And you can do edits inside the review, which for me is quite robust.

Comment: Though clicking the link *does* give away that it's an audit, it does not, however, sidestep the whole *gist* of audits: they are there to catch robo-reviewers, and a robo-reviewer will likely not actually click the link (they'll just straight away click the review button).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is the desired behavior.  It's not *that* uncommon for a reviewer to either need additional information on a post that can only be found by going outside of the review system, or to take an action that is not an option provided from within the review system.